# How to skip a Parameter with Default Values in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

My Groovy method has 3 parameters and the last 2 have default values. I want to skip the second parameter, and only provide values for the first and the third like so..

```
 def askForADate(girlsName, msg = 'Will you go out with me?', beg = 'pretty please!!') {
    println "$girlsName, $msg $beg!"
 }

askForADate('Jennifer',,'Because I love you!')
```

Right now this prints out...

```
 Jennifer, Because I love you! pretty please!!!
```

So it looks like it is plugging the value I am passing in for the third parameter into the second.

How to fix that?

Comment: You'll need to write a two arg version or pass null/blank string for the second parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As doelleri said, you'll need to write two version of thie method.
Unless you'll use some groovy goodness with named arguments!

```
def askForADate(Map op, girlsName) {
    println "$girlsName, ${op.get('msg', 'Will you go out with me?')} ${op.get('beg', 'pretty please!!')}!"
}

askForADate(beg: 'Because I love you!', 'Jennifer')
```

Prints out: Jennifer, Will you go out with me? Because I love you!!

See http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2015/09/groovy-goodness-turn-method-parameters.html for more details

This solution has the clear disadvantage of reordering the arguments as now the girls name is last in line.

Comment: It's possible to call `askForADate('Jennifer', beg: 'Because I love you!')` as well. An overload without the `Map` argument, to require no optional arguments at all, can be also defined as well.